# Unity AdMob Не показывает рекламу на телефоне

Tags: unity3d, admob, google-adsense, встроенная-реклама

Помогите пожалуйста. Уже неделю сижу с этим. Реклама в Google AdMob работает в Эдиторе, но ни в какую не хочет показываться на телефоне. Ни тестовая, ни реальная.

Версия плагина 8.6.0
Версия юнити 2022.3.16f1

Вот код менеджера рекламы:

```
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    public string adUnitId;
    void Start()
    {
        RequestInterstitial();
    }
    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

        // Clean up interstitial before using it
        if (interstitial != null)
        {
            interstitial.Destroy();
        }

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        InterstitialAd.Load(adUnitId, request, (InterstitialAd ad, LoadAdError loadAdError) =>
        {
            if (loadAdError != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            if (ad == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Debug.Log("Interstitial ad loaded");
            interstitial = ad;

            ad.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += HandleOnAdFullScreenContentClosed;   //  >>>> HERE <<<<

        });
    }
    public void HandleOnAdFullScreenContentClosed()
    {
        Debug.Log("Interstitial ad Closed");
    }
    public void ShowInterstitialAd()  // Show
    {
        if (interstitial != null && interstitial.CanShowAd())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Метод ShowInterstitialAd() вызывается по кнопке.

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедись в правильности данных аккаунта.
2. Убедись, что все настройки аккаунта сделаны правильно. Имя, адрес, номер телефона и информация по платежам в AdMob аккаунте верифицированы корректно.
3. Верификация адреса через пинкод?
4. Файл app-ads.txt корректный?

5 . "policy center" ошибки выдаёт?

6 . У тебя приложение выложено и залинковано с AdMob? (Google play?)

7. Проверь настройки eCPM и убедись, что выставленная цена не слишком высока
8. "AdMob требуется валидные аккаунты AdSense и Google Ads. Сервисы и платежи AdMob завязываются на эти аккаунты, поэтому убедись в том, что используешь правильные аккаунты. После создания аккаунта AdMob происходит привязка и просто так потом не изменить уже.

Погляди этот гайд, если ещё не видел:
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356173?hl=en

Проверь верификацию аккаунта AdSense тут:  https://www.google.com/adsense/start/
AdSense > payment > там всё верифицировано?

AdSense > account  > Access and authorization  всё готово там?
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2659101?hl=en

Проверь, чтобы аккаунт google ads был активен

google ads, admob и adsense должны быть зарегистрированы на одну почту.

9. admob > setting > Account Information > seller information > поменяй на > Transparent, если не менял.

Погляди ещё тут https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685?hl=en

10. В стартовом гиде под разные устройства тоже погляди, может что-то забыл.
    Android - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
    IOS - https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start
11. Проверь, включены ли метрики?

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9263723

12. Проверь статус для приложения тут: admob > Apps > your app > Approval status > Написано ли там "Ready"?

Надеюсь это тебе поможет, друг!